# How to take out the summation $\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}$ out of the $2$-norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

How to take out the summation $\sum\limits_{l=1}^{\infty}$ out of the $2$-norm?

Consider the $2$-norm of the double summation $\left\|\sum\limits_{l=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_{kl} x_{kl}\right\|_2$, where $a_{kl}$ are the scalars.

I want to decompose with respect to the $j$ by bringing out the summation $\sum_{l=1}^\infty$ out of the norm symbol.

We know by definition of $2$-norm, $\|x\|_2^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^2$, for $x=(x_1,~x_2,\ldots)$.

How to take out the summation $\sum\limits_{l=1}^\infty$ out of the norm ??

Comment: You can't apply the 2-norm to a number. The 2-norm is for sequence in your case. How about write it down like a sequence?

Comment: @Oolongmilktea, ok, you just consider general case for sequence . In the particular case, I assumed the rest terms $l,k \geq 2$ is $0$. Any how can you answer the case for a sequence ?

Comment: In you case, it is $\leq$, since well-defined norms satisfy the triangle inequality. To prove the triangle inequality of the 2-norm, you may use the Cauchy inequality..

Comment: But I'm confused by your notation, there are only numbers in the norm and the 2-norm is just the absolute value.